# has_secure_password creating a user even though password and passowrd_confirmation do not match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rubygems

I'm using has_secure_password in my user model. On sign up I'm giving password and password confirmation fields .

I manually added validation to check if the password and confirmation match in my user model.

```
has_secure_password
validates :password, presence:true, length: {minimum:6}
validate :pass_valid
def pass_valid
    errors.add(:base,"password and confirmation do not match") if password!=password_confirmation
end
```

my form looks like this

```
= f.label :'Password'
= f.password_field :password
= f.label :'Password Confirmation'
= f.password_field :password_confirmation
```

The form is giving error even when I enter a password confirmation that is different from password. I take that has_secure_password verifies that password and confirmation both match and I removed pass_valid method. Now user is created even though the password and confirmation do not match.

Can someone help me out?

P.S : I'm using protected-attributes in my gemfile. So added password and password_confirmation to attr_accessible in user model.

Comment: Where are you stating that the validation is based on both fields been equal?

Comment: Sorry! My mistake in copy pasting. Edited

Comment: I think you should be using validates_with, instead of validates .

Answer (score 0):

Try using `validates_with :yourValidator`, which would be pass_valid in this case.

Comment: Looks like the password confirmation in my form is always taken as blank. Don't know why. I added an extra validation for password confirmation for its presence. It says password confirmation cannot be blank even though I enter password confirmation.

Comment: Are you certain that you put the password_confirmation as an accessible attribute in your model?

Comment: yea! as I said in my p.s , I added them in attr_accessible